# Weird error when running a simple vue.js app

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-router

I'm using vue.js 2.x and just set up a simple app using webpack.

When i start the app in dev mode, i get this error in chrome console and nothing is displayed on the page:

> Uncaught TypeError: _vm._m is not a function(…)

there is no error on the server (no webpack error).

**Routes.js**

```
import Home from './components/Home.vue';
import Portfolio from './components/portfolio/Portfolio.vue';
import Stocks from './components/stocks/Stocks.vue';

export const routes = [{
    path: '/',
    components: Home
}, {
    path: '/portfolio',
    components: Portfolio
}, {
    path: '/stocks',
    components: Stocks
}]
```

**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'
import { routes } from './routes'

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
<script>

    export default {

    }
</script>
<style>

</style>
```

**Home.vue**

```
<template>
    <h1>The home component</h1>
</template>
```

Any idea what is causing it?

Comment: Could you please post you `webpack.config.js` file here ? Your i so far so good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as usual, it was a silly mistake, I had a typo in the routes definitions,
I used `components` instead of `component`:

```
export const routes = [{
    path: '/',
   //should be component
    components: Home
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably move away from trying to use `render` on your Vue instance when testing.

You should have a root file like `index.html` which creates a container for your app and calls the App component:

```
#index.html
<div id="my-vue-app">
    <app></app>
</div>
```

Then edit main.js, replacing the way you initialise your Vue instance with the following:

```
new Vue({
  components: {
    App
  },
  router
}).$mount('#my-vue-app')
```

Comment: I'm using a starter kit from a udemy course which is used by thousands, also, behind the scenes, vue calls the render method so there is really no difffrence

Comment: no, apparently i had a typo in the routes definitions: components instead of component

Comment: may also be good to check that vue-router is the latest version: 2.0.2